# Not able to get room's event which is created by other users. in graph Api

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

It is really nice to have work with MS Graph API.
We are using this apis for our product.

Actually we need to get the All rooms of a User and assosiated events of the rooms.
We are able to fecth the rooms. but we are facing few issues with events.

Our requirnment for events is we have to fetch all the events w.r.t one room irrespective of who has created the events.
Currently we are getting the events which are created by me.

NOT GETTING EVNTS OF A ROOM CREATED BY OTHERS

FYI we are using auth flow with the below url

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenatId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=redirectUrl&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read%20places.read.all calendares.read&state=12345

and we are using below url to fetch the events

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/?select=id,subject,start,end,location,organizer,originalStartTimeZone&orderby=start/dateTime&filter =isCancelled eq false &top=100&endDateTime=endDateTime&startDateTime=startDateTime

Please let us know if there is any different api to fetch the rooms related all events with the token which we are getting with the above login flow.

We have checked all the documentaion but not getting expected data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below API for the above requirement

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"room_email_id"/calendar/calendarView](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%22room_email_id%22/calendar/calendarView).

"room_email_id"  should be replaced with the actual value

Thanking you